# NestableException cannot be resolved when using apache.commons.configuration

Tags: eclipse, class, collision, resolve

Im using the following:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;
```

and i get:

```
The type org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Im using eclipse...

how can i resolve this? he offers me to Configure build path but i dont really know how to solve this collision from there.....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Problem solved...
had to download the commons-lang-2.4.jar and include in project.

couldnt be more simple than that....

Comment: I think it worths to say that `commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar` or above doesn't work. It has to be up to the `commons-lang-2.6.jar`. Thanks for your answer, solved my problem.

Comment: what an absolute mess, what if my project need a newer common lang?

Comment: @FelicePollano You can add both versions to your project

Comment: Worth noting that installing 2.6 alongside current most recent (3.4) worked  resolved this for me - i know this is an old thread but may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what is really needed is an update to the PropertiesConfiguration lib so that it gets along with latest lang lib. If its a "free" lib then it might not be coming, considering that its been years since last reply on this thread and this is still happening.
I have been having this issue as well, and have not found a way of resolving it apart from the aforementioned inclusion of both lang libs ... which does not seem to present any problems, though strict repository framework implementations (like Maven) might have problems with both libs included.

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove commons-lang3-3.4 from my Java Build Path and added 2.6 , it solved the problem!